# Is there functionality to request an Uber on another person's behalf?

Tags: uber-api

My business opportunity would benefit from being able to request an Uber to pick up a client and arrive at my place of business, and not just the client requesting the Uber themselves. Is this something that I can do today with Uber?

edit: the origin of my request would be different than the requested pick-up location.

Comment: I've requested rides for other people before. The app will have you confirm that you indeed want the ride if the origin of your request varies from the point of pickup--though I'm not sure what the tolerance is.

Comment: yes, my usecase would be the origin and pick-up locations would differ. I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> The Uber API gives you the ability to Request an Uber Product on behalf of users within your application. Given you know where a user currently is, where they want to go, and which Uber product they want to use to get there, you have all of the tools to make that happen with a few simple API endpoints.

Looks like I answered my own question :)